# Are there pumpkins in Minecraft 0.7.1?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make a Snow Golem, but all I need to do is get a jack-o-lantern. But I can't find any pumpkins.

Comment: Based on http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Pocket_Edition It doesn't appear like pumpkins or jack-o-lanterns are available yet.

Answer (score 1):

Only melons are available in Pocket Edition right now. Also, snow golems, Iron golems, and endermen are not implemented into Minecraft Pocket Edition as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not, sadly. I haven't found any proof saying No, but I can't edit them into the game and the wiki page doesn't talk about PE on the pumpkin page.